# A positive function that is less than its derivative for all x?

Tags: calculus

Does there exists a positive function (i.e $f(x) > 0$) such that for all $x > 0$ it is less than it's derivative (ie $f'(x)$)?  Intuition says this would not be possible, but is there a more formal proof of this?

Comment: not sure what you mean? How about $\exp(2x)$?

Answer (score 2):

One thought might be to naively start drawing a picture. As long as the picture is hyper-increasing, one might intuitively recognize that this is possible.

You could also think to find a solution to a differential equation. For instance, is there a solution to $f'(x) = 2 f(x)$ that is always positive? If so, then it satisfies your condition by design (the derivative is always twice the value of the function). And yes, there is a solution: $f(x) = e^{2x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Such a function does exist. Take $f(x) = \exp(2x) > 0$. By the chain rule,

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \exp 2x \\&= \exp'(2x) \cdot \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} 2x \right) \\&= \exp(2x) \cdot 2 \\&> f(x).
\end{align*}